# PHP Identifying First Data of An Array Using For Each Loop

Tags: php

Let's say I have this array :

```
$cars = array("Saab","Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
```

and I also have this Foreach loop to 'manipulate' that array :

```
foreach ($cars as $carsdata) 
    { 
        if (*this is array[0]) {
            do something here
        }else if (*array[1] ... array[x]){
            do another thing here
        }        
    }
```

any idea how to write that Foreach correctly? thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case your array is number-indexed, so actually you can do this:

```
foreach ($cars as $index => $carsdata) 
{ 
    if ($index == 0) { // array[0]
        do something here
    } else { // *array[1] ... array[x]
        do another thing here
    }        
}
```

Comment: Beaten to it, it seems. exposing the index will solve most foreach-related problems

Answer (score 8):

You could include a simple boolean like this:

```
$firstRow=true;
foreach ($cars as $carsdata) 
{ 
    if ($firstRow) 
    {
        $firstRow=false;
        // do something here
    }
    else
    {
        // do another thing here
    }        
}
```

Comment: +1... best solution if array has valued keys, or unsorted numbers.

Comment: @glavić Don't sell yourself short, your answer is excellent based on the question as it stands :)

Answer (score 5):

If you have indexed array $cars like your entered in question, then this will work :

```
foreach ($cars as $i => $carsdata) {
    if (!$i) {
        // do something with first
    } else {
        // do something with second+
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

```
foreach ($cars as $key => $carsdata) {
     if ($key == 0) {
        //do
    } else {
        //do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility

```
$i = 0;
$len = count($carsdata);
foreach ($cars as $carsdata) 
{ 
    if ( $i == 0 ) {
        // first element
        // do something here
    }else if ($i == $len - 1){
        // last element
        // do another thing here
    } else {
        // do the rest here
    } 
    $i++;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($cars as $carsdata=>value) 
{ 
    if($value==0){
        // Do the things for the o th index 
    }
    else{


    }
}
```